# Showing the URL of the view in the address bar, instead of the one of the action

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "updatePatient", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView postUpdatePatientById(
        @ModelAttribute("patient") PatientForm patientForm,
        HttpSession session) {
    Long id = (Long) session.getAttribute("refId");
    if (id != 0 || id != null) {
        Patient patient1 = HospitalPatientHelper
                .getPatientFrom_PatientForm(patientForm);
        patientService.updatePatient(patient1, id);
        PatientService patientService) {
    Patient patient = patientService.getPatientById(id);
    ModelAndView mv;
    PatientForm patientForm = HospitalPatientHelper
            .getPatientForm_FromPatient(patient);
    List<Weight> weights = patientService.viewLast10RecordedWeight(patient);
    WeightTable weightTable = new WeightTable();
    List<WeightSummaryTable> summaryWeights = weightTable.summary(weights,
            patient.getHeight());
    mv = new ModelAndView("patient1/patientDetail");
    mv.addObject("patient", patientForm);
    mv.addObject("summaries", summaryWeights);
    mv.addObject("lastWeight", summaryWeights.get(0).getWeight());
    mv.addObject("bmi", summaryWeights.get(0).getBmi());
    return mv;
    } else {
        return new ModelAndView("patient1/patientDetail");
    }

}
```

the page shown sucessfully, but the url dosn't change, means the url is not showing the address `www.url.com/patient1/patientDetail.htm`

and i want that the returning view address should also be shown in the url too.

please help me

Answer (score 1):

Use either

```
new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(patient1/patientDetail)).
```

Or

```
redirect:patient1/patientDetail
```